# using web browser in visual studio 2008 for windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

I used web browser component in my app for windows mobile...
I set the url as `"www.google.com"` but it shows

`"page is unavailable,u need to adjust browser settings!!!
cannot find server or DNS error"`

Do I need to do any sort of coding from my end
as I set the url from the property box of web browser component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answser :

```
 private void webBrowser1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
     webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
 }
```

When you sync your application the first time with WMDC, you must go ahead with setup partnership.

```
Check the checkbox for allow the connections and choose DMA
```

Also select :

```
The computer is connected to "The Internet"
```

and you are done!